# How to embed database in javadb with my javafx standalone database application

Tags: netbeans, javafx, derby

I am creating a desktop application using JavaFx with database integration. When I  run the Java DB  server from programfiles/sun/javadb it shows me ClassNotFound Exception but the same thing when i run from NetBeans IDE it works.. So please tell me how to make my application run without NetBeans IDE. I also want to create its exe. How can we embed database with JAR. while creating exe.

Comment: Look into [Berkeley DB](http://www.oracle.com/us/products/database/berkeley-db/overview/index.html)

Answer (score 0):

You will need to include the Derby jar files (at least derby.jar, maybe some others) in your application CLASSPATH.

Answer (score 0):

I'm an Eclipse user so I can't help you with Netbeans but here how it's done in Eclipse: in this explanation I used JPA in Java SE (this is from a real project so I hope I could help)

First export the the project as a jar:

- Click File -> export -> and choose Java/Runnable JAR file -> Click
  Next
- -> Eclipse automatically will find and select your Main class + select the location where you want eclise to save the JAR file
- -> select **package required libraries into generated JAR** -> click finish.

[image]

Next, I assume you create your database manually, let's assume the the db folder is called **finance**. now put the db folder in the same folder as the JAR, I used JPA in this project of mine so here is the persistence.xml

```
<persistence version="2.1" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd">
    <persistence-unit name="FinanPU" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
        <provider>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider</provider>
        <class>lite.money.entities.Category</class>

        <!-- <shared-cache-mode>NONE</shared-cache-mode> -->
        <properties>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedDriver" />
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:derby:finance;" /> <!-- Derby -->

            <property name="eclipselink.ddl-generation.output-mode" value="database" />
        </properties>

    </persistence-unit>
```

this line:

```
<property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:derby:finance;" />
```

as you can see **finance** is the path to your DATABASE FOLDER, and since it's a relative path; the db driver will search for the folder in the same folder that the JAR exist.

and this how I embed JavaDB with JavaFX applications (using JPA of course).